# Changed sectionNameKeyPath attribute value is not reflected on NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: core-data

I have a table-view backed by an NSFetchedResultsController.

Any time an object in the underlying context changes, the NSFetchedResultsController automatically reflects new attribute values on the table-view. Yay.

The one exception I have noticed is that updates to the attribute value used for sectionNameKeyPath are not reflected automatically.

I'm guessing the attribute value used for the sectionNameKeyPath is so fundamental to the NSFetchedResultsController that I'll need to performFetch & reload the table-view again?

**Update**: heres the code used to configure the fetch request

```
- (void)configureFetch {

CoreDataHelper *cdh = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cdh];

NSFetchRequest *request =
[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Item"];

request.sortDescriptors =
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"locationAtHome.storedIn"
                               ascending:YES],
 [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                               ascending:YES],
 nil];
[request setFetchBatchSize:15];
self.frc =
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                    managedObjectContext:cdh.context
                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"locationAtHome.storedIn"
                                               cacheName:nil];
self.frc.delegate = self;
}
```

and the code to perform the fetch:

```
- (void)performFetch {

if (self.frc) {
    [self.frc.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        NSError *error;
        [self.frc performFetch:&error];
        if (error) NSLog(@"%@ '%@' %@ (Reason: %@)",
                         self.class, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd),
                         error.localizedDescription, error.localizedFailureReason);

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }];
}
}
```

Comment: Can you show your code creating the fetched results controller (with the fetch request, predicate, sort descriptors)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the attribute used as `sectionNameKeyPath` is changed, but that an attribute in a *related object* is changed.

A fetched results controller tracks only changes to the fetched objects itself (the *Item* objects in your case), but not to related objects.

The only solution (as far as I know), is to add the section as an additional attribute to the *Item* entity, even if that means that you have duplicate data.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll work around this issue by sending a notification to performFetch whenever this value changes. Thank you for your prompt response!